# Are redundant terms removed from expressions at compile time

Tags: c#, optimization, compilation

Are redundant terms in expressions removed at compile time.

Say I have and of the following lines

```
a = b / 1;
a = b * 1;
a = b + 0;
a = b - 0;
a = b << 0;
a = b >> 0;
```

Will the compiler optimize these to just simply `a = b;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed it does. You can open the disassembler in Visual Studio under `Debug` -> `Windows` -> `Disassembly` to see for yourself. I wrote this:

```
        int a, b;
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        b = a / 1;
        b = a * 1;
        b = a + 0;
        b = a - 0;
        b = a << 0;
        b = a >> 0;

       Console.WriteLine("{0}", b);
```

and turned on Optimization for Debug build. In the disassembly I got this:

```
000007FE974040F4 E8 F7 62 D1 5E       call        000007FEF611A3F0  
000007FE974040F9 89 45 E4             mov         dword ptr [rbp-1Ch],eax  
000007FE974040FC 8B 4D E4             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-1Ch]  
000007FE974040FF 89 4D EC             mov         dword ptr [rbp-14h],ecx  
            b = a / 1;
000007FE974242C2 8B 4D EC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-14h]  
000007FE974242C5 89 4D E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],ecx  
            b = a * 1;
000007FE974242C8 8B 4D EC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-14h]  
000007FE974242CB 89 4D E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],ecx  
            b = a + 0;
000007FE974242CE 8B 4D EC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-14h]  
000007FE974242D1 89 4D E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],ecx  
            b = a - 0;
000007FE974242D4 8B 4D EC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-14h]  
000007FE974242D7 89 4D E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],ecx  
            b = a << 0;
000007FE974242DA 8B 4D EC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-14h]  
000007FE974242DD 89 4D E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],ecx  
            b = a >> 0;
000007FE974242E0 8B 4D EC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp-14h]  
000007FE974242E3 89 4D E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],ecx
```

You can see the assembly instructions are the exact same for each line, it's just copying `a` to `b` six times. Actually I'm surprised it doesn't optimize the whole thing to a single `b=a` instruction. If I comment out the `Console.WriteLine` it does:

```
000007FE974041D4 E8 17 62 D1 5E       call        000007FEF611A3F0  
000007FE974041D9 89 45 E8             mov         dword ptr [rbp-18h],eax  
000007FE974041DC 8B 45 E8             mov         eax,dword ptr [rbp-18h]  
000007FE974041DF 89 45 EC             mov         dword ptr [rbp-14h],eax  

            b = a / 1;
000007FE974041E2 90                   nop  
            b = a * 1;
            b = a + 0;
            b = a - 0;
            b = a << 0;
            b = a >> 0;

         //  Console.WriteLine("{0}", b);

        }
000007FE974041E3 90                   nop
```

Although in *that* case I'm surprised it doesn't optimize out `b` entirely, since it is never used. Maybe someone else can explain it.

Comment: Note that answer is for question that OP likely is interested to but not the one they asked - "Will redundant assignments be removed from final JIT'ed code". Answer to exact question should show IL and not ASM.

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out the tool and also for the detailed answer.

Comment: You're welcome. On another look at the second code, I actually see it is optimizing `b` out, the first three `mov` instructions are just copying the result of `Convert.Int32()` to `a`. But then you'd think it would optimize `a` out too, and just ignore the result of the function call. Oh well.